# Angular JS + Isotope: "sort by" throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-isotope

I am trying to get [Isotope 2.2.2](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and [Angular Isotope](http://mankindsoftware.github.io/angular-isotope/) to work together.  I have the grid working, and filtering works perfectly.  My problem arises with Sorting.

I constructed json data similar to the one in his example, each item having a date and a name, and am using an angular ng-repeat to create the isotope items. As I said, this is all working, and filtering with buttons works like a charm.

According to the instructions, adding sorting works by adding a second button group like so:

```
<h4>Selector and Value-Based Sort</h4>
<div class="btn-group" opt-kind="" ok-key="sortBy">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ok-sel=".name">Name</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ok-sel="[date]" ok-type="integer">Date</button>
</div>
```

I did this, and tried many ways, but every time I add the `ok-sel` attribute, the whole thing takes a dive and I get an angular error in the console:
`TypeError: $elem.find is not a function`

I have tried removing and adding things, and even with one button, there are no errors (but of course the button does nothing) without the `ok-sel` attribute in the sort buttons.

Any suggestions?